# ng-change() dentro de un marker (ngMap) en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con sockets, donde envio cada cierto tiempo coordenadas (lat, lon) y para mostrar estas coordenadas utilizo ngMap, cuando tengo una primera coordenada ésta se muestra en mi mapa pero si me llega una segunda coordena el marker se duplica, es allí donde deseo utilizar ng-change() para que cuando hayan nuevas coordenadas remover el marker y crear siempre uno solo. a continuación comparto mi código:

```
<ng-map id="mapa_inicio" center= "-3.989785, -79.205805" zoom="13">        
   <marker ng-repeat = "u in ubicacion track by $index"
      position="{{conversion(u.latitud)}},{{conversion(u.longitud)}}" tittle={{u.id_ruta}} ng-change="remover_marker()">
    </marker> 
</ng-map>
```

js:

```
$scope.remover_marker = function(){
console.log("aqui haré el control deseado")
}
```

Mi error es que el ng-change() no sirve, Como lo puedo resolver? de antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 0):

Lo más conveniente es eliminarlo y hacerlo aparecer en las nuevas coordenadas, este es un ejemplo de un controlador para agregar, mostrar, eliminar markers.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('MarkerRemoveCtrl', function(NgMap) {
  var vm = this;
  NgMap.getMap().then(map => vm.map = map);
  vm.positions = [{lat:37.7699298,lng:-122.4469157}];

  vm.addMarker = function(event) {
    var ll = event.latLng;
    vm.positions.push({lat:ll.lat(), lng: ll.lng()});
  }
  vm.deleteMarkers = function() {
    vm.positions = [];
  };
  vm.showMarkers = function() {
    for (var key in vm.map.markers) {
      vm.map.markers[key].setMap(vm.map);
    };
  };
  vm.hideMarkers = function() {
    for (var key in vm.map.markers) {
      vm.map.markers[key].setMap(null);
    };
  };
});
```

En esta web puedes encontrar todos los usos de ng-map.

https://ngmap.github.io/